# How do I get rid of this Sigabrt error? I've tried Multiple Ways

Tags: ios, swift, sigabrt

So I am new to programming on xcode. I just started a week ago but constantly watched coding videos and looked at coding examples. I have very small background with this but am in search for learning so much more about coding.

### The Situation

I am working on my app and try to simulate it through an Iphone 5s simulator. I have my main view controller linked to the second view controller by a UIButton. When I press the button, Nothing happens and I recieve a red little warning saying:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Next to where it says "UIResponder, it will say "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" This is how my viewcontroller.swift editor looks like:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  QuoteDaily
//
//  Created by Jordan Norris on 2/5/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Jordan Norris. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var Button: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

### What I have done so far

I looked at other post like this and the answers say to get rid of any lingering outlets and unattached things that may be causing this problem, so I get rid of every outlet and connection and start "fresh". The only problem is, When I add a button to go to the second ViewController,"FirstQuestion.swift", it will show the same error.

I also restarted xcode many times and restarted the simulator a lot of times and the same error pops up.

### The Question

What I'm asking for is how do I get rid of this error so that I can push this button to bring me to the second view controller?

I have 2 pictures for reference

[Assistant text editor for first view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKNkz.png)

[View Controller number 1(with the button) and view controller 2(When is your birthday) *Also the triggered segues and referencing outlets on the left side*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dOci.png)

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me because I don't feel like giving up on something I just started. Also this community seems like a very friendly one so I'd love to come back to this source for any further help. Thank You.

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: What does the console say? How are you connecting the button to the second view controller? Of course, if you're doing a segue, your first view controller should be embedded inside a `UINavigationController` (there's an "embed in" menu option somewhere close to the Product menu when clicking the view controller, check it out). It would be **really helpful** if you link to a video with the steps you're doing (better yet with screenshots than a video).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Select Your second viewController to which the button is pointing and check all the outlets connections you have made by going to **Show the connections inspector**. Sometimes there are some previously connected outlet or actions names that you may have changed, that may cause crash.

Remove all connections and connect them again by **selecting show the assistant editor**. Clean the code and run the project again if it helped.